# App's radio buttons require *double* accelerator press on one PC

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button, acceleratorkey

I'm developing a C# Windows Forms app and have assigned accelerator keys to its radio buttons using & in the Text property. I must have done this a thousand times without trouble in other apps. But when I install this app on some PCs, I can click ALT + the accelerator letter to click the associated radio button. On my dev PC this key combination with this app merely moves focus to the radio button but doesn't click it. If I press the letter again then the radio button is clicked. This wierdness only affects radio buttons...checkboxes work normally. I tried a different keyboard but no relief.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Does it matter what accelerator key you use?  Have you tried a different key as a test?

Comment: It was not dependent on key.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot fixed it. Seriously? Sometimes it's best not to ask why.